# Using PGAL10 promoter to overexpress specific yeast genes: How to?

Tags: gene-expression, cloning, yeast

I was reading a poster about expression boosting for Artemesinin production in yeast and it had this line:

> PGAL1
>   and PGAL10 have been used for the
>   overexpression of all genes from the mevalonate
>   pathway.

What exactly does this mean? I suppose these are promotors? http://www.yeastgenome.org/locus/S000000224/overview

But how exactly does one use them during cloning to boost expression?

Say that you wanted to over-express ERG10, the gene coding for the first enzyme in the MVA pathway. How does one go about using PGAL10 to do this during the cloning steps?

Link to the poster: https://ddd.uab.cat/pub/tfg/2014/119349/TFG_narcisferrerledo.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You're right about them being promoters, although it would be useful if you posted the link to the source of the sentence that you cite, so that we can read exactly how they are being used.

A fairly common way to study genes that aren't consistently highly expressed is to place them under the control of a strong promoter; that is, a promoter that is recognized by transcription factors in such a way that its linked gene is almost always expressed.

This is exactly what this group did in [this paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1461455/), to study some features of yeast metabolism. In this case, the genes that they were interested in studying were cloned into a vector that was then inserted into yeast cells that lacked that gene. This way, the researchers knew that any expression of their gene of interest came from the vector and was driven by the pGAL1 promoter.

Similarly, if ERG10 was your gene of interest, this might be a strategy that you could adopt to study it.

Comment: I added the link to the source. It's a poster not a review, sorry. https://ddd.uab.cat/pub/tfg/2014/119349/TFG_narcisferrerledo.pdf

Comment: And this is a related paper: http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v496/n7446/full/nature12051.html

Comment: From the poster, it looks like they're doing what I describe in my answer. That is, over-expressing a gene from a plasmid and driving that expression with a strong promoter. I think you'll see that a lot in studies like this one.

Comment: So how does one go about finding the actual DNA sequence for what they call PGAL1 / PGAL10. A search for these on Genebank / Yeast databases produced no hits.

Comment: Ok, maybe I did find the sequence! Would it be this one, you think? http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/218616465